# How can I prove this property of a projection?

Tags: linear-algebra

In linear algebra and functional analysis, a projection is a linear transformation P from a vector space to itself such that P^2 = P. That is, whenever P is applied twice to any value, it gives the same result as if it were applied once.( [Projection (linear algebra)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28linear_algebra%29) )

How can I prove property 2:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x\in U$. Since $U$ is the range (image) of $p$, there exists $z\in W$ such that $u=p(z)$. Use now the fact that $p^2=p$ to get $p(u)=u$.

> That is, $p(u) = p(p(z)) = p^2(z) \stackrel{\rm (*)}{=}p(z)= u$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x'$ be in the range. Then, $x'=P(x)$ for some $x \in W$. But then $P(x')=PP(x)=P(x)=x'$. Hence, $P(x')=x'$, and we have that $P$ is the identity on $U$.